# Запуск redmine

Tags: redmine, debian

Устанавливаю redmie по вот этому [мануалу](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_2_integrated_with_Gitolite_2_on_Debian_Wheezy_with_Apache_and_Phusion_Passenger)

Возникли проблемы с базой данных mysql

**RAILS_ENV=production rake redmine:plugins:migrate**

```
    rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Table 'redmine.settings' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `settings`
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:211:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:259:in `execute_and_free'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:426:in
```

**Уточнение вопроса:**

**rake db:create**

```
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:63:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

В общем даже непонятно с чем проблемы

Comment: RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate не забыли?

Comment: К сожалению тоже самое.  Не хочет создавать таблицы

Comment: @NEPSTER 4234223, думаю, что ошибка там все-таки другая

Comment: @Fike 

rake db:create
database configuration does not specify adapter

Comment: @NEPSTER 4234223 в конфиге адаптер укажите же

Comment: production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: redmine
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: "мой мароль"
  encoding: utf8

Comment: Энвайронмент перед запуском команды указали? Конфиг точно от продакшена (не помню, как орагнизованы конфиги в рельсах)?

Comment: "Энвайронмент перед запуском команды указали?" честно не знаю что это!

Да, кроме своих логинов и паролей к бд больше ничего не менял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@NEPSTER 4234223](/users/13983/nepster-4234223), указание энвайронмента (среды) - это строчка RAILS_ENV=production
В гугле куча таких ошибок (database configuration does not specify adapter), но 90% из них сводятся к каким-то пропущенным мелочам. Судя по RAILS_ENV=production rake redmine:plugins:migrate, сам коннект у вас подхватывается, просто редмайн к этому моменту не развернул свои миграции.

Comment: а что ж тогда делать?

Comment: @NEPSTER 4234223 RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate (именно с RAILS_ENV) делали?

Comment: да, тоже самое

Comment: есть разница из какой директории запускать?

Comment: Да, нужно из директории  с приложением, иначе будет непонятно, откуда конфиги брать. У вас почему-то не читается конфигурация по адаптеру, там точно после двоеточия пробел стоит?

Comment: перепроверил, да пробел есть. Кодировка utf8.

Comment: Я бы все удалил и начал установку заново. Корней в системе редмайн нигде пустить не должен был.